# Is it possible end-to-end tests using react-testing-library?

Tags: react-testing-library

I know that we can test the component label test using the React Testing Library. But from my curiosity, I want to know that is there any way to do an end-to-end test on the react components using this library.

I'll be grateful if I get some nice information on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an example of using React Router within the RTL docs: https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/ so it looks like it's possible. However, I'd recommend using a dedicated e2e testing library such as [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) to do the job. There is an [RTL integration for Cypress](https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro/) so you can follow the same testing principles that RTL advocates.

Comment: Good answer  Although the downside of e2e testing with cypress, selenium or other is significantly slower and cumulatively limits the ci tests on each build. Despite not being true browser experience both react testing library and enzyme provide  lightening equivalent to e2e and tests can be cleverly crafted to emulate near equivalent e2e flow with majority component expectations . E2e is still needed, but a lot of time and ci process can be shaved and saved.